Why is a mobile app hosting third party content "navigation" but a website hosting third party content "reproducing / embedding"
Wasn't sure whether to post this in the legal stackexchange or the web development one- apologies if I've chosen wrong here.
I am developing a mobile app and a website, where collected recommended articles are being shown to the user alongside an image and text of the source's origin. Clicking on the article on the phone app opens "webview" (a default in-app browser your phone has) and navigation to the content of the page is done inside the app. This constitutes our app as a "gateway" for the user to access their preferred content, and effort is made to ensure we aren't framing said content as originating from the app (overlay for navigation, header displaying source site name, unchanged content display), hence it's easy to argue I'm not bypassing TOS of the source webpages, and they're happy to allow me to access them.
However when attempting to replicate the same idea on my website version, I found the origin webpages to be refusing to allow access to the page's content due to X frame security policy- I am accessing it from my website's URL as opposed to their own, which goes against their policy of refusing to allow embedding (even when I am attributing all content to them quite clearly). A workaround would be asking for explicit permission from the source website- unfortunately my sources is a very large list of number of companies, some of whom are very large. As a fix for my website I have simply linked any articles to opening in a new tab so as to be compliant with their terms of service refusing to allow embedding or reproduction.
My question then: even were I to get around this X frame issue, the display of content within an iframe with full attribution would still be classified as an embedding or reproduction of their content on a website- where the same exact code on mobile is a legally acceptable position of navigation. What is the reasoning behind this somewhat arbitrary platform distinction when it comes to implementing copyright refusals of embedding? It seems to me like every argument for one side would apply to the other, though of course maybe the answer is I don't understand where the law would be applied enough to be able to even claim this distinction exists in the first place. Why is hosting the third party content on a mobile app somehow seen as more legitimate than doing the same thing on my website version of the same app, when the only code even changed between the two is a conditional import of suitable webview packages?

X frame security policy has nothing to do with the law. Its a security policy implemented by the website designer.  You cant get around it without duplicating the content elsewhere.  And that would be violating the copyright.
The dumb server does not understand that you are attributing anything to anyone.  That has nothing to do with it.
The law portion of your question belongs on the Law site.

absolutely! was just surprised that duplicating the content serverside, storing in cache so I'm making less requests and then displaying that content to the users is suddenly illegal where the exact same visual effect achieved on mobile apps is seen as legitimate. Thanks for the guidance here, will move my question over.
